# Creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a `d` column to a DataFrame.
When creating the `d` column, the conditions are as follows:

If it starts with 11 in column `a`, it gets the value in column `b`, otherwise it gets the value in column `c`.

```
a     b    c
11101 100  150
11201 200  250
13301 300  350


a     b    c    d
11101 100  150  100
11201 200  250  200
13301 300  350  350
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.where` after converting the column `a` into `str`:

```
df["a"] = df["a"].astype("str")
df["d"] = np.where(df["a"].str.startswith("11"), df["b"], df["c"])
```

or if you don't want to change datatype of `a` in original dataframe

```
df["d"] = np.where(df["a"].astype("str").str.startswith("11"), df["b"], df["c"])
```

Comment: Also there's a native pandas Series.where() for this:
`df["d"] = df["b"].where(df["a"].astype("str").str.startswith("11"), df["c"])`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use lambda function:

```
df["d"] = df.apply(lambda x : x["b"] if str(x["a"])[:2] == "11" else x["c"], axis =1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df["d"]=0
for(i , x in enumerate(df["a"])):
  if str(x).startswith("11"):
    df["d"][i]=df["b"][i]
  else:
    df["d"][i]=df["c"][i]
print(df)
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code or expound on why this is the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it readable, I would prefer the use of an external function (`calculateValue`) in the lambda function

```
def calculateValue(a, b, c):
  if(a.startswith('11')):
    return b
  else:
    return c

df["d"] = df.apply(lambda row: calculateValue(row["a"],row["b"],row["c"]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `numpy.vectorize` which can be a bit faster.

```
import numpy as np


def get_d(a, b, c):
    return b if str(a)[:2] == '11' else c


df['d'] = np.vectorize(get_d)(df.a, df.b, df.c)
```

Comment: np.vectorize is a sheer for-loop, as given explicitly in the documentation, so I wouldn't expect any substantial boost. Where() (numpy- or pandas-style) should be a true vectorized solution to this.